# Jaeger agent not receiving spans from Node.JS client

Tags: node.js, docker, jaeger, open-telemetry

I am working on a backend composed of multiple microservices, and I want to be able to view the spans in the Jaeger UI. I use `docker-compose` to run my containers, including jaeger, and opentelemetry to generate and send spans. I have followed the [troubleshooting guide](https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/1.32/troubleshooting/) up to and including the logging reporter.

This is my first time working with jaeger and this kind of architecture so I feel a bit lost at this point.

Here are some relevant parts of my code, some logs and screenshots :

#### Docker-compose.yaml

```
x-aliases :
  - &jaeger_envs
    JAEGER_SAMPLER_TYPE: const
    JAEGER_SAMPLER_PARAM: 1
    JAEGER_ENDPOINT: http://127.0.0.1:14268/api/traces

api-gateway:
    build: ./src/api-gateway/
    container_name: api-gateway
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_DB_URL: user-db:27017
      QUEUE_SERVICE_URL: queue-service:5001
      STATUS_SERVICE_URL: status-service:5002
      TICKET_SERVICE_URL: ticket-service:5003
      JAEGER_REPORTER_LOG_SPANS: 'true'
      <<: *api_gateway_envs
      <<: *jaeger_envs
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - user-db
      - queue-service
      - status-service
      - ticket-service

jaeger:
    image: jaegertracing/all-in-one:latest
    container_name: jaeger
    restart: always
    environment:
      COLLECTOR_ZIPKIN_HOST_PORT: 9411
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:5775:5775/udp"
      - "127.0.0.1:6831:6831/udp"
      - "127.0.0.1:6832:6832/udp"
      - "127.0.0.1:5778:5778"
      - "127.0.0.1:16686:16686"
      - "127.0.0.1:14268:14268"
      - "127.0.0.1:14269:14269"
      - "127.0.0.1:14250:14250"
      - "127.0.0.1:9411:9411"
```

#### /src/ticket_service/tracing.ts

```
import { NodeSDK } from "@opentelemetry/sdk-node";
import { getNodeAutoInstrumentations } from "@opentelemetry/auto-instrumentations-node";
import { JaegerExporter } from '@opentelemetry/exporter-jaeger';
import { SemanticResourceAttributes } from '@opentelemetry/semantic-conventions';
import { Resource } from '@opentelemetry/resources';

const jaegerExporter = new JaegerExporter({
  endpoint: 'http://127.0.0.1:14268/api/traces', //hardcoded to make sure this is not an env var issue
});

const resource = new Resource({
  [SemanticResourceAttributes.SERVICE_NAME]: 'api-gateway',
});

const sdk = new NodeSDK({
  traceExporter: jaegerExporter,
  instrumentations: [getNodeAutoInstrumentations()],
  resource: resource
});

sdk.start();
console.log("tracer initialized");
```

I run the api-gateway micro-service with `cross-env NODE_ENV=production NODE_PATH=dist/ node -r ./dist/src/tracing.js ./dist/src`

#### Api-gateway logs :

```
{"body":{"email":"test@test.com","password":"***"},"duration":30.636999999999997,"level":"debug","message":"POST /api/auth/sign-in - 401 - 30.64 ms","method":"POST","originalUrl":"/api/auth/sign-in","params":{},"path":"/api/auth/sign-in","remoteIp":"::ffff:172.18.0.1","remotePort":59534,"span_id":"596fa50386bd55a1","state":"outgoing","status":401,"timestamp":"2022-03-23T10:34:22.102Z","trace_flags":"01","trace_id":"8278acbbfb7c59ffb2296d96660f005e"}

{"body":{"email":"test@test.com","password":"***"},"duration":5.9342999999999995,"level":"debug","message":"POST /api/auth/sign-in - 401 - 5.93 ms","method":"POST","originalUrl":"/api/auth/sign-in","params":{},"path":"/api/auth/sign-in","remoteIp":"::ffff:172.18.0.1","remotePort":59534,"span_id":"704d7a23ae3cb1e1","state":"outgoing","status":401,"timestamp":"2022-03-23T10:34:23.562Z","trace_flags":"01","trace_id":"7dd1c34706602bab47e5ca78a78dd7cc"}

{"body":{"email":"test@test.com","password":"***"},"duration":3.6582999999999997,"level":"debug","message":"POST /api/auth/sign-in - 401 - 3.66 ms","method":"POST","originalUrl":"/api/auth/sign-in","params":{},"path":"/api/auth/sign-in","remoteIp":"::ffff:172.18.0.1","remotePort":59534,"span_id":"eace80cc6146a8fb","state":"outgoing","status":401,"timestamp":"2022-03-23T10:34:24.750Z","trace_flags":"01","trace_id":"15d1e13cd8e17558bd6624e069336219"}
```

#### Jaeger Agent container log related to the HTTP endpoint

```
{"level":"info","ts":1648028283.2791674,"caller":"flags/admin.go:115","msg":"Starting admin HTTP server","http-addr":":14269"}
{"level":"info","ts":1648028283.2952828,"caller":"server/http.go:48","msg":"Starting jaeger-collector HTTP server","http host-port":":14268"}
```

#### Screenshot of the Jaeger UI

[Jaeger UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XL8F0.png)

Any help or idea would be greatly appreciated !
Have a good day !

Comment: Could you try to configure the endpoint like this: `endpoint: 'http://jaeger:14268/api/traces'`? Let me know if works, I'll be happy to send the comment as an answer.

Comment: @JulianoCosta That was it ! Thank you so much ! I let you add it as answer and I will validate it and close the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to think of a container as an individual minimal host. And in that case, when you say to your `ticket_service` app to call `localhost` it will call itself, which is not what we want.

Whenever using docker-compose, a docker network is created and the containers are configured to use it.
You can use that network to make your containers communicate with each other by their names.

In your case, as the Jaeger container is called `jaeger`, you have to configure the endpoint of your JaegerExporter as follows:

```
const jaegerExporter = new JaegerExporter({
  endpoint: 'http://jaeger:14268/api/traces'
});
```